Weirdest properties of Banach spaces?
This is soft question, but I've recently have become interested in the odd properties of Banach spaces after studying Banach spaces which do not admit a pre-dual.  I also almost work exclusively with Hilbert space / C*-algebras, so my knowledge of general Banach space theory is limited to the average functional analysis PhD student's.
What are some (non-obvious) odd properties of Banach spaces that have been discovered which aren't issues for Hilbert space?  Are there any interesting open questions in general Banach space theory still?  I only know of a few mathematicians that still study Banach space theory as a research area.

Unfortunately, I am not an expert in functional analysis  but the first thing that comes to my mind is the "nasty" Banach space $\mathfrak X_{AH}$ constructed by Argyros and Haydon in which every operator is a compact perturbation of a scalar operator, i.e. of the form $λ+K$ with $K$ compact. Interestingly, this space has the invariant subspace property (another great topic on its own) i.e. every operator has a non-trivial invariant subspace. You can see Gower's weblog for more details.

(cont.) Since you mentioned $C^*$-algebras, another bizarre property that the Argyros Haydon space has is that the calkin algebra $B(\mathfrak X_{AH})/ K(\mathfrak X_{AH}) \simeq \mathbb C$ (in hilbert spaces $B(H)/K(H)$ is infinite dimensional and much less trivial)
